# Injective map from a module of finite rank to free module

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, local-rings

Let $R$ be a reduced Noetherian ring and $M$ be a finitely generated $R$ module of rank $n.$ Let $\operatorname{Ass}(M)\subset \operatorname{Min}(R).$

*How to show that*

**there exists an injective $R$-linear map $f:M\longrightarrow R^n$**

I think if the existence of a map from $M$ to $R^n$ can be shown then injectivity comes from the fact that $R$ is reduced and $\operatorname{Ass}(M)\subset \operatorname{Min}(R).$

Comment: What do you call the *rank* of a non-(necessarily)free module?

Comment: @Bernard If Q is total ring of fractions of R the n M has rank n means M tensor with Q has free rank n over Q.

Comment: But this is  strong condition on $M$: not all finitely generated modules  have a rank, if $R$ is not and integral domain, I guess.

Comment: I am assuming that M has rank

Comment: Your condition implies the natural map $M\to M^{**}$ is injective. Now, let $R^n\to M^*$ be a surjection, then $M^{**}\subset R^{n^*}\cong R^n$.

Comment: @Mohan Could you please explain how to get a surjection from R^n to dual of  M

Answer (score 0):

Let $S$ be the set of non-zero divisors of $R$. Note the assumption implies that $M \to S^{-1}M$ is injective, because $S = R \setminus \bigcup_{P \in Min(R)} P$ does not meet any associated primes of $M$.

By assumption $S^{-1}M$ has a $S^{-1}R$-basis $e_1, \dotsc, e_n$ and w.l.o.g we have $e_i \in M$.

Now consider the map $f:M \to S^{-1}M$ and let $m_1, \dotsc, m_t \in M$ be generators of $M$. We have $m_j = \sum\limits_{i=1}^n \frac{a_{ij}}{s_j}e_i$ for   and $f(M) \subset \sum\limits_{i=1}^n R\frac{e_i}{s}$ for $s = s_1 \dotsb s_t \in S$. But this sum is clearly direct, since the $e_i$ are $S^{-1}R$-linear independent.

Thus we have shown that $f$ is an injective map $M \to \oplus_{i=1}^n R\frac{e_1}{s} \cong R^n$.

---

One can rephrase this for the more experienced user: By assumption we find some non-zerodivisor $t \in R$ an isomorphism $M_t \xrightarrow{\cong} (R_t)^n$, which yields injective map $M \to M_t \to (R_t)^n$. By the finite generation of $M$, we deduce that the image is actually contained in $(t^{-m}R)^n$ for some $m \geq 0$. Hence we have an injection $M \to M_t \to (t^{-m}R)^n \cong R^n$.

Comment: Since M is finitely generated, I think the map f can be constructed clearing denominators of the isomorphism between S^{-1}M and S^{-1}R^n. Is that correct?

Comment: No this might be not surjective.

Comment: If you read my proofs carefully, you will notice that I never did that...

Comment: I did not say that f is surjective

Comment: Still, this makes no sense. In general you do not get a map $M \to N $ from a map $S^{-1}M \to S^{-1}N$. Have you even tried to understand my proof?

Comment: I did not say that from any localization I will get that map. Since M has rank n and we have the particular isomorphism. In your proof I think you can talk about direct sum because of that isomorphism.

Comment: I thought my proof is very detailed. Do you have a concrete question? Honestly, I do not see your problem. Why do you wanna rephrase it in a certainly wrong direction?

Comment: I want to know that if M,N are finitely generated modules and we have a surjection from S^{-1}M onto S^{-1}N  then we will always get a map from M to N.  I think this can be done by clearing the denominators.

Comment: Of course you get a map, but this could be even the zero map.

Comment: In my question S is the set of nonzerodivisors and Ass(M) is inside Ass(R). I think in this case I will get a nonzero map.

Comment: This is what I proved.

Comment: But I do not think that 'Clearing denominators' is a sufficient description of the proof. Actually you consider the map $M \to S^{-1}M \to S^{-1}N$ and show that it factors over some $s^{-1}N$. This is isomorphic to $N$, if $s$ is $N$-regular. So you also need that Ass(N) is inside Ass(R).

Comment: Yes and it holds for my original question

Comment: Obviously. ${}$